# Angular2 cli (Webpack) creating chunks for different modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am working on an Angular2 application with large no of separate modules. The module specific files(js,css,html) are fetched only when module is created dynamically (...using moduleFactory and createComponent).

So I need to bundle my app in such a way that instead of having single bundle.js,   I want each module as a separate chunk so that the chunk(js) is only fetched when the module is created.

how can I achieve this in angular cli ?? 
will CommonsChunkPlugin be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your project with webpack directly without using angular-cli and use `require.ensure()` to include external file dynamically. Webpack will detect  `require.ensure()` and will create a separate chunk for it.